# How to convert "YYYY-MM-DD hh mm ss" to "YYYYMMDDhhmm" using xslt

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt-2.0

I have date in xml as "YYYY-MM-DD hh mm ss", need to convert that into "YYYYMMDDhhmm", can anyone help me with xslt date formatters ?

```
 <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(dt)) = ''">
  <INVDTE>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(dt)"/>
  </INVDTE>
  </xsl:if>
```

XMl:

```
<dt>2020-01-02-15.49.01.000001</dt>
```

Expected:

```
202001021549
```

Comment: Your title and text says you have the input format `YYYY-MM-DD hh mm ss`, your sample has dots between the time components and a dash between the date and time in `2020-01-02-15.49.01.000001`. As for the conversion, either simply use string operations to get rid of spaces, dots, dashes and then take the substring of the wanted string length or convert the input with string operations to the `xs:dateTime` format and use `format-dateTime` with the needed picture string to output the wanted format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is `translate(., '- ', '')` to remove the punctuation, then `substring(., 1, 12)` to remove the seconds value.